# Can a single nVidia GTX 1080 drive more than 4 monitors?

Tags: nvidia-graphics-card

The maximum resolution for an nVidia GTX 1080 is 7680x4320. If I have 6 screens with a total resolution bellow that number, is it possible to drive them with a single card? How do I connect them since the card only has 3 display ports and 1 HDMI connectors?

Would a Display Port splitter help? I'm not entirely sure what they do: [https://www.amazon.com/Monoprice-2-Port-DisplayPort-Multi-Stream-Transport/dp/B075754ZYC/ref=sr_1_3?dchild=1&keywords=displayport+splitter&qid=1589790533&sr=8-3](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B075754ZYC)

Answer (score 2):

No, there is no direct way to connect more monitors to a card than the number of monitor outputs it has.

You may be able to go higher using a screen stitching device like the Matrox Dual/Triple Head2Go, but that requires an additional external piece of hardware.

Comment: Additionally, depending on the card manufacturer, rather than the chipset manufacturer, a given card may not even support all its physical connections simultaneously.

Comment: Indeed, most only support 3 simultaneous outputs.

Comment: Mine supports all 4 of them. I already had 4 monitors connected, or 3 monitors and a VR headset.